# Android auto reset of mediaplayer when activity starts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Following on from previous question which it appears that no one can provide a solution, is it possible to reset the mediaplayer automatically, I do not want the user to press buttons to reset, when new activity starts.
Currently it appears that it is not.

Comment: what you mean new activity start?

Comment: reset the media player before calling the activity

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (mediaplayer!= null) {
            mediaplayer.reset();
            mediaplayer.release();
            mediaplayer= null;
        }
```

Apply this code in below activity:

1)this code will apply on destroy of previous activity/pause of this activity.

2)on create method of new activity.(using intent)